# Azure web job, service bus trigger not triggered for old messages available in the queue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-webjobssdk, dead-letter

I have implemented the azure web job to consume messages from azure service bus. Service bus trigger works fine for new messages arrived to service bus but its not picking up the messages that were already available on the service bus before service start. Is there any configuration to get existing messages to the web job?

Due to some reason, some messages got abandon. What are the best ways to reprocess these messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get messsage and can't complete or abandon it 10 times(default), the message will go dead queue.

You can get dead queue like this.

```
_messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(QueueDescription.Path), ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
```